# Is there an in- or out-of-universe explanation on how Gerald McBoing-Boing is able to imitate sound effects only?

Tags: dr-seuss, gerald-mcboingboing

In the children's story *Gerald McBoing-Boing* by Dr. Seuss the titular character is a human living with his parents and their dog. The kid is odd because he doesn't speak a word. He communicates just by imitating sound effects (such as telephone, paper being torn, etc.)

Is there an explanation on how he is able to imitate sound effects with 100% accuracy and he isn't able to speak (and even imitate) human words?

Comment: [Related question on Movies and TV Stack Exchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/121288)

Comment: @verbose That question is also asked by me. Of course I'm not a sockpuppet. I don't have a "Etack Sxchange" account in Literature SE, nor a "Snack Exchange" account in Movies and TV SE.

Comment: Have you heard of [Michael Winslow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Winslow)? Granted he can also speak "human words"...

Comment: @SnackExchange Nobody's accusing you of being a sockpuppet; I think what verbose is trying to get at is that it's frowned upon to post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @F1Krazy you're correct of course that it's frowned upon to post the same question across multiple sites here, but I don't think this is an example. The question on MTV asks about the movie version, this about the Seuss book. I commented simply because the questions are obviously linked.

Answer (score 5):

In what follows I look within the text and also seek external explanations for Gerald’s lack of verbalization and amazing  vocal mimicry of sounds arrive at a conclusive consensus

Gerald’s failure to reach expected language milestones at age 2 and the development of his mimicry left his father concerned and transiently [grey](https://archive.org/details/geraldmcboingboi00seus/page/n9/mode/2up). Dr. Malone the family doctor is consulted and after reviewing the child admits [defeat](https://archive.org/details/geraldmcboingboi0000seus/page/n13/mode/1up?view=theater) with the words:

> I’ve no cure for this.
>
> I can’t handle the case
>
> And he packed up his pills
>
> And walked out of the place.

This leaves the parents (and perhaps Gerald too) high and dry. However, aside from lack of speech and his impressive mimicry he seems to be an otherwise normal toddler and develops as such. His vocal mimcry likewise develops with resulting parental disquietude. On reaching school going age (5 years) he was sent to school in the hope that he might ‘learn words’, but gets sent away from school quite soon after. He arrives back home with a note pinned to his coat from his first-grade teacher with the dire warning in the [note](https://archive.org/details/geraldmcboingboi00seus/page/n17/mode/2up) that he will go “honk” all his life.

For Gerald this and other events over time take their [toll](https://archive.org/details/geraldmcboingboi00seus/page/n21/mode/2up) and  lead to a growing sense of alienation and frustration  leading him to run away from home. While  waiting to board a train he is recognized  by a Broadcast Media executive who after an impromptu audition extends a job offer as a foley artist. After accepting this, Gerald becomes famous and financially [secure](https://archive.org/details/geraldmcboingboi00seus/page/n31/mode/2up?view=theate) and [functions  well socially](https://archive.org/details/geraldmcboingboi00seus/page/n33/mode/2up?view=theater), but he remains bereft of speech.

So, no obvious direct explanation for his gift mimicry and inability to generate speech emerges *in universe*.

In the external world does this ability for vocal mimicry  of sounds exist: It does and has been well [documented](http://cognitioninthewild.wp.st-andrews.ac.uk/files/2013/05/Kelly-2011-Vocal-Mimicry.pdf) in the animal world. Likewise, among humans it exists in a variety of guises one such is [beat boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatboxing).

Recognizing details pertinent to the case may narrow down Gerald's issues as symptoms and signs of medical problem (it makes sense to survey the issue of his problems from all angles). We know that age of onset of the sound mimicry was at 2 years but he was unable to [speak](https://archive.org/details/geraldmcboingboi00seus/page/n9/mode/2up). We know from perusal pictures in the book that he can understand speech, read, write, and otherwise he develops normally. The outstanding pathological traits are the absence of speech and the presence of superior sound mimicry.

With this in mind the  possible medical diagnostic possibilities arise and include, but are not limited to:

1. A stroke syndrome such as [Broca’s Aphasia](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK436010/#:%7E:text=Broca%20aphasia%20is%20a%20non,use%20of%20prepositions%20are%20lost.) of with loss of expression and preserved comprehension of speech appears  possible. But the neuroplasticity of young children would mean that the speech loss is transient with a return to normal speech over time.
2. Aphemia is a similar neurological  syndrome with a wider subset of underlying aetiologies than stroke. It approximates more closely with Gerald disability than aphasia does. More details on this informative [page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8442164/).
3. The phenomenon may be explained by invoking the vocal tics of echopraxia or  echolalia associated with [Tourettes Syndrome](https://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/tourette/facts.html#:%7E:text=Tourette%20Syndrome%20(TS)%20is%20a,keep%20blinking%20over%20and%20over.). However, the later onset -5 years of age and over- makes this less applicable and the absence of clear correspondence in the other clinical features diminishes the possibility further.
4. PANS/PANDAS syndromes are conditions with an underlying autoimmune cause and may include vocal tics (akin to Tourettes)  with an earlier age of onset (at 3 years ): [More here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PANDAS).
5. An autistic spectrum disorder of the high functioning variety cannot be excluded and it sits comfortably among the diagnostic possibilities. (In passing  should point out that labels such as Aspergers Syndrome, Suchareva Syndrome, and Idiot Savant though applicable are considered pejorative and have been retired from use for a variety of reasons so I have not used them here).
6. A psychiatric diagnosis such as [selective mutism](https://www.asha.org/practice-portal/clinical-topics/selective-mutism/).

Despite all this, his lack of speech and his facility for auditory mimicry had not left him worse off,indeed far from it: he had thrived  as a result of it! Ms. Schultz dire predictions proved to be false. Dr. Malone’s non-involvement after his confession of defeat had perhaps been ultimately beneficial to Gerald and indeed to all concerned!

Gerald when we leave him at the end of Dr. Seuss’s  biography of this child’s early life and rise to fame seems to be a well-adjusted young man gainfully employed and  as a result of his amazing ability has a bright future ahead of him and this lack of speech had not resulted to any significant to extent in being an impediment rather it has been an asset.

Dr. Seuss’s dedication to the improvement of literacy is well known through his works; In response to what was perceived to be a problem with early childhood literacy he produced [The Cat in the Hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cat_in_the_Hat). But in addition, his works are noticeably full, indeed quite bulging at the seams with wacky, wild and whimsical characters. Is this not clear evidence of an attempt to acknowledge, recognize, and respond positively to difference? Thus, it might be said this is another possible interpretation of underlying message and therefore explanation of Gerald McCloy’s story whose incidental sound effect mimicry and lack of speech represent a vehicle for the furthering of this aim.

The style, the tone and the overall narrative bring attention to another point: This is a work of [surreal whimsy](https://medium.com/@amereattempt1/dr-seuss-the-quintessential-surrealist-5fbf547b60f4) and as such the search for logical explanations and reasons is ultimately bound to be  superfluous.

This leaves Ourselves, Gerald and all the Cast of characters comfortably ensconced in the theatre of the mind to let this story cycle through with the rhythm and rhyme of written word with the visual garnish of the good doctors' illustrations  delight, amuse and enetertain with every flip of the page.

Comment: Thank you very much. Doesn't Dr. Seuss also have any interviews explaining about Gerald and his special ability?

Comment: I am unaware of any specific explanatory comments by Dr. Seuss ( but this does not rule them out )  .